# How to Use The Same Table With Different Entities In EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have entity DbDropPhoto with navigation property

```
public class DbDropPhoto
{
    public virtual DbContour Contour { get; set; }
}

public class DbContour
{
    public virtual DbDropPhoto CurrentDropPhoto { get; set; }
}
```

Relationship configured like this using FluentAPI:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<DbContour>()
        .HasRequired(s => s.CurrentDropPhoto)
        .WithOptional(s => s.Contour)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

now I need to add same DbContour entity to another entity called DbThermalPhoto. What is the best way to do it. Should I create separate table for example DbThermalPhotoContour or I can somehow re-use existing table. I've searched for similar questions but solution to them seemed to be very complicated.

Comment: I want to re-use DbContour table. So i've had DbDropPhoto with DbContour entity, now i want to add DbContour entity to new entity DbThermalPhoto

Comment: Look for *polymorphic associations*. There are many *many* questions in this area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve it like this:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<DbDropPhoto>()
            .HasOptional(c => c.Contour)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.ContourId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<DbThermalPhoto>()
            .HasOptional(c => c.Contour)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.ContourId);
```

And Entities:

```
[Table("DropPhotos")]
public class DbDropPhoto
{
    [Key] public Guid PhotoId { get; set; }

    public Guid? ContourId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContourId")]
    public virtual DbContour Contour { get; set; }
}

[Table("ThermalPhotos")]
public class DbThermalPhoto
{
    [Key] public Guid PhotoId { get; set; }

    public Guid? ContourId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContourId")]
    public virtual DbContour Contour { get; set; }
}
```